# Restful web service call with input parameter as Java Object

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

Am using rest call for my spring application. I need to send Java objects as input parameter for the rest methods. Once i have tried using requestentity for inputstream. is it suitable for that?

the code i used for inputstream is

```
HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
           restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9070/EXTJS4FileUpload_Rest/rest/fileUpload/send/"+filename+"/"+filesize,entity,String.class);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate and share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: instead of passing request entity on above url..i need to send java object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read Java objects as stream in REST method you need to Deserailize the stream to object ( I dont know why and how u managed to do so). Instead try sending java object as JSON or XML and after consuming in REST method convert into object using by parsing XML/JSON . If you use frameworks like Jersey it fairly simple by specifying request mime-type

Comment: Looking at your code i think you are trying to post an java object as a part of HTTP Request ... Then you CANNOT ... HTTP is not only for java and it does not understand Java and need not to.. You need to create JSON out of object and send it as part of POST body not GET request